# Finding the value of C in this function

Tags: polynomials, factoring

If $$x^2 + (c-2)x -c^2 -3c + 5$$ is divided by $x + c$, the remainder is $-1$. find the value of c

I replaced all the x value to -c and set it to an equation which equated to $-1$

I am confused what to do after that, show me the steps how I can retrieve the value of $c$

Comment: If you perform the substitution $x\mapsto c$ you can't get more than a quadratic in $c.$ What's confusing about that? Don't you know how to solve quadratic equations?

Answer (score 1):

Given that:
$$\begin{align}x^2 + (c-2)x -c^2 -3c + 5 & = (-c)^2 + (c-2)(-c) -c^2 -3c + 5 \\
 & = c^2 - c^2 +2c -c^2 -3c + 5 \\ 
  c^2 +c -5& = 1 \\ 
 c^2 +c-6  &= 0  \\ 
(c+3)(c-2) & = 0 \implies \color {blue}{ \boxed {\text { c = 2 , -3}} }\end{align}  $$